# zsh alias expansion

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Is it possible to configure zsh to expand global aliases during tab completion?  For example, I have the common aliases:

```
alias -g '...'='../..'
alias -g '....'='../../..'
```

but when I type, for example, `cd .../some<tab>` it won't expand to `cd .../something` or `cd ../../something`.  Consequently, I frequently won't use these handy aliases because they are incompatible with tab completion.

Comment: Look in `man zshcompsys` and search for "_expand_alias". Sorry, I haven't had a chance to learn zsh completion in depth. You also might try asking on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a user of Mikael Magnusson's `rationalise-dot`. From my zshrc:

```
# This was written entirely by Mikael Magnusson (Mikachu)
# Basically type '...' to get '../..' with successive .'s adding /..
function rationalise-dot {
    local MATCH # keep the regex match from leaking to the environment
    if [[ $LBUFFER =~ '(^|/| |      |'$'\n''|\||;|&)\.\.$' ]]; then
      LBUFFER+=/
      zle self-insert
      zle self-insert
    else
      zle self-insert
    fi
}
zle -N rationalise-dot
bindkey . rationalise-dot
# without this, typing a . aborts incremental history search
bindkey -M isearch . self-insert
```

Comment: This is very interesting, and sort of solves the example case, but doesn't solve the general case.  (I say "sort of" because it doesn't wait until you hit `<TAB>` to expand from `...` to `../..`.)

Answer (score 6):

Try looking up **zsh abbreviations**. They allow you to enter an "abbreviation" which automatically gets replaced with its full form when you hit a magic key such as space. So you can create one which changes `...<SPACE>` to `../..`.

For example, this is what you need in your profile:

```
typeset -A abbrevs
abbrevs=(
        "..." "../.."
        "...." "../../.."        
)

#create aliases for the abbrevs too
for abbr in ${(k)abbrevs}; do
   alias -g $abbr="${abbrevs[$abbr]}"
done

my-expand-abbrev() {
    local MATCH
    LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#}
    LBUFFER+=${abbrevs[$MATCH]:-$MATCH}
    zle self-insert
}

bindkey " " my-expand-abbrev
```

Comment: For that matter, you can just type `...` and press `Ctrl-X a` using only normal `alias -g` aliases.

Comment: @Dennis: can `<TAB>` be made to do *both* do its normal completion *and* `_expand_alias` (`Ctrl-X a`)?  If so, wouldn't that solve the problem as it is stated in the question?

Comment: @dogbane: This gives me "No such widget `my-expand-abbrev'" in zsh 4.3.10

Comment: @iconoclast It looks like you need to add `zle -N my-expand-abbrev` before the `bindkey` now.

Comment: @EricBoehs: that prevents the error message, but it doesn't make the expansion take place.  (`Ctrl-X a` does, though.)  I'm now on zsh 5.0.2, if that changes anything.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing something. I have my full working set up here: https://github.com/ericboehs/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/abbreviations.zsh. It's probably the extended globs.